# What does it mean to add power to a Mastermind?

Tags: legendary-marvel

In the instructions for Legendary: A Marvel Deck Building game, a way of increasing difficulty is to "Add +1-5 Power to the Mastermind."

What does that mean? My guess is that it increases its Attack (i.e. the number you need to hit the Mastermind with to defeat them), and I could be blind here but I don't see this clarified anywhere in the rules that come with the game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't an officially maintained FAQ or Errata for Legendary, but from a few pieces of evidence we can confirm your guess is correct; **Power** is **Attack**.

Firstly, the only number that could be added to on all masterminds is the Attack.
Secondly, when the designer Devin Low [posts on boardgamegeek](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/902144/article/10950669#10950669) he uses [POWER] to reference attack modifiers.
and Finally, if you pull apart the official rules PDF this symbol [image: power] is referenced by `/Power`, leaving the potential for the mixed terminology ultimately being a careless typesetting error

Comment: Good-enough detective work in my book. Well done, and thanks for the answer.